# iOS css border corner join issue

Tags: css, ios5, border

I am applying CSS borders to div and I am not getting corner joins of border properly in iOS 5 as you can see in following image. Any help would be appreciated... Thanks

[image]

Following is being used to generate DIV

```
<div id="divSelection" style="position: absolute; border:3px dashed red; z-index: 1000; width: 305px; height: 206px; left: 50px; top: 50px; -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); "></div>​
```

Comment: Push your code for better understanding

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by "corner-joins"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this, this is bug in iOS 5, for some reason, it doesn't render dashed styled css border properly.

open following link in iOS 5

[Border test](http://old.macedition.com/cb/resources/safari/bordertest1.html)

It appears only solution for now is to apply border radius with dashed border property then it will render corners properly.